# Выбрать четыре дня текущей недели, включая сегодняшний и три случайных

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Нужно выбрать 4 дня недели, включая сегодняшний. Желательно использовать инструменты, входящие в Laravel, так как проект создан с помощью этого PHP фреймворка.

Я сделал по такой схеме:

```
// Сегодняшний день + еще `n` дней

Carbon::now()->addDay(n)->isoFormat('dddd');

// где n = Arr::random(1,6);
```

Возможно есть другие решения. Подскажите варианты реализации задуманного.

Comment: Мне нужно в таком формате - сегодня:вторник + еще 3 случайных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;

$days = [];
$now = Carbon::now();

// Формируем массив ключей для семи дней недели.
$keys = range(0, 6);

// Удаляем текущий день.
// dayOfWeekIso - возвращает число текущего дня недели
// между 1 (понедельник) и 7 (воскресенье).
unset($keys[$now->dayOfWeekIso - 1]);

// Выбираем случайные три дня.
$rand_keys = array_rand($keys, 3);

// Создаем массив из дат в периоде
// для начала и конца текущей недели.
$period = CarbonPeriod::between(
  $now->copy()->startOfWeek(),
  $now->copy()->endOfWeek()
);

// Перебираем массив дат, оставляя необходимые.
// `isSameDay` - тот же день того же месяца того же года.
foreach ($period as $key => $date) {
  if (in_array($key, $rand_keys) or $date->isSameDay($now))
    $days[] = $date->locale('ru')->isoFormat('dddd');
}

dd($days);
```

На выходе получаем: сегодня вторник + еще 3 случайных:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "понедельник"
  1 => "вторник"
  2 => "четверг"
  3 => "суббота"
]
```